# How to use expression blend

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend

I want to style my control in `Expression Blend`, But when I run Expression Blend I get an error.
[image]
With the error is a link attached to download Blend + Sketch Flow, but I can't find the download. Where can I download Blend + Sketch Flow for WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going for Expression blend 5, I suggest you to go for Expression blend 4 as it is stand alone installation and not require any other program to install.

Comment: i have installed visual studio update 4 . but how can i use it.

Comment: Please use Expression blend 4, it will work for you as it has nothing to do with visual studio.

Comment: from where I can get download link of expression blend . I have searched but unable to find. please give me the link , if it is possible for you.Thank you .

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5915 you can find trial version for expression blend 4.

Answer (score 0):

If you install VS2012 update 2 or 3, Blend for VS 2012 it  will automatically support WPF and Silverlight development. The preview version is no longer recommended.

It is there with the default installation when you install VS2012

Add/Remove Programmes ->Select VS 2012 and Clicking Change ->Click Modify in the VS installer->
Tick the Blend for Visual Studio option

Comment: sir I downladed visual studio 2012 update 4 from this link 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305
and also installed it . but no option to open blend

Comment: check modified answer

Comment: thanks for response. let me do what you said, then I'll  comment.